# Phonegap Command failed with exit code 74

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Trying to build my Phonegap app in the terminal and getting these errors. Where do I go from here? Is there a way to identify the code 74?

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project
>
> cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.
>
> Error: phonegap Command failed with exit code 74.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I believe it's because I was linking to:     `xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">`

but I should have been linking to:
`xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`